# Malicious requests detecting/validating requests

Tags: validation, security, request

Application has front-end and back-end modules, front-end calls rest services from the backend written on Java/Spring.
Is there any best practices how to detect malicious request generated not by the front-end (if some user try to call service direcly from the back-end via rest client)?

Maybe generating some hash value for every request on front-end and decrypt this value on back-end validating this request?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is authentication. The backend needs to authenticate either the frontend web app, or the user itself.

Probably the most common way is authenticating the frontend, which practically means that frontend and backend have a shared secret, authentication takes place upon each call, and the backend trusts the frontend. This can be achieved in countless ways from http basic auth (over https of course) to some kind of an api key mechanism (signing requests, etc.) You don't have to reinvent the wheel, depending on your usecase and threat model, http basic auth over https may very well be enough.

Another way to do things is to delegate user credentials to backend services. This is most often achieved by passing single sign-on tokens from the user to the backend, effectively impersonating the user when the frontend calls backend services. Arguably this is more secure, as for instance it does not need that level of trust between web and app, but services still need to trust the SSO component that issued the token. The point is that there is no secret for an adversary to steal (let alone from the frontend server, which may be an easier target), so it may be more difficult for an attacker to issue requests to backend services, even if some backend and/or frontend servers are already compromised.

So while I think an answer here is not the right format to go into details about how exactly to do this authentication (there really are multiple good solutions, and in every case, implementation details matter very much), at least conceptually these are your options I think.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but application already have authentication and authorization services.

Comment: What is the question then? The purpose of authentication and authorization is to make sure who the caller is and only allow authorized callers to perform actions. This applies to backend services just as well as to frontend apps.